# Can I make a product which infringes on a patent for my own use (not for resale)

Tags: patentability

I wanted to make a carbon fiber hockey stick on my own, then I realized there is already an issued US patent on it. Is it against the law to make a oval hockey stick for myself, not for resale?

Answer (score 2):

Patents give their owner an exclusive right to *make*, sell, offer for sale and *use* the covered subject matter. Making and using, themselves, are on the list. The only enforcement of patent rights is by the patent owner, the government can not go after patent infringers. Given that you can assess the benefits and risks.

Comment: I am not a lawyer, but It would seem logical, that if you're just some guy practicing on hockey sticks in your backyard, it's unlikely that the patent holder would really care, (but you could contact them about this individual use?), but if you're a pro hockey player, and want one, and want to use it in pro games, they'll probably get upset.